# How to get a specific page content?

Tags: wordpress

The following code is working nice but it's not coming with HTML tags, like `<span>`, `<b>`, `<strong>`, etc.

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
<?php 
echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,450);
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
   More About Us
</a>
```

This is another code which outputs HTML tags and everything ok, but I can't figure out how to do the permalink there. The permalink I put there is not working.

```
<?php
$my_id = 2;
$page_id = get_post($my_id);
$content = $page_id->post_content;
echo substr($content, 0, 450);   
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >More About Us</a>
```

Also, what is the best way to get a specific page content, like in the example bellow?

```
<h2>title</h2>
<div>featured image </div>
<div>content</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

```
$permalink = get_permalink($page_id->ID);
```

As per your other requests

**Title**

```
$title = $page_id->post_title;
```

**Thumbnail** ([get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail))

```
$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($page_id->ID);
```

**Content**

```
$content = $page_id->post_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

i just found solution

```
 <?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2"); while($recent->have_posts()) : 
$recent->the_post();?>
    <?php 
    echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,450);

     ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
             More About Us
              </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

i used `substr(get_the_content) instead of get_the_excerpt` now it working fine.